# Is it possible to modify content of Order new modal?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, button-overrides

In Orders tab there is a "New" button, that opens a modal to create an order. I'm trying to modify it's content, and add some custom code in there (showing dynamic customer based options).

Nothing has worked for me so far.
Edit: No matter what I change in the component, it just won't show my component.

I use Lightning Experience. And Illuminated Cloud 2 to push/pull my code.
I'm able to create apex classes, triggers, lightning components, visualforce pages.

Here is one of the things I tried and think it should be the way:

In 'Object Manager > Order > Button, Links, and Actions > New' tried on many different lightning components and visualforce pages.

a test component:

```
<aura:component description="OrderNewCmp" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" controller="OrderNewCmpController">

    <aura:attribute name="newOrder" type="Order"/>

    <p>JUST TO TEST</p>
    <form>

        <ui:button label="Submit" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" labelClass="label" press="{!c.createOrder}"/>
        <ui:button label="Cancel" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" labelClass="label" press="{!c.Close}"/>

    </form>

</aura:component>
```

and apex controller:

```
public with sharing class OrderNewCmpController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Order saveOrder(Order ord) {
        upsert ord;
        return ord;
    }

}
```

component controller.js

```
({
    createOrder: function (component, event, helper) {
        var newOrder = component.get('newOrder');
        var action = component.get('saveOrder');
        action.setParams({
            'ord': newOrder
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function (result) {
            var state = result.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
                var name = result.getReturnValue();
                alert('complete ' + name);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: So what’s the issue that you are facing when you say nothing works? And moreover your component never calls the aura save method in your apex controller.

Comment: My component just won't show up

Comment: You need to implement `force:hasRecordId`.

Comment: I've also tried that too, and still won't change the content.

Comment: It just showed up, I refreshed the page multiple times. and just suddenly showed up!!!